# Find posterior distribution for uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior, posterior, uniform-distribution

Given X with uniform distribution in the interval [μ,μ+θ].

1. Suppose θ is given. Find the posterior distribution with prior distribution on your own.
2. From that, find the Bayesian estimator with quadratic loss function.
3. If θ is not given, how to find μ.

Actually, this is a tough question in my last exam and I don't know how to approach it. I have read some papers and I solved it based on what I got.

**My solution:**

[image]

[image]

***And I don’t know how to proceed. 
Is it correct with this approach? Please give me some explanations. Thank you very much.***

Answer (score 3):

Good try:

1. The posterior density is indeed proportional to
   $\mathbb{I}_{xn-\theta\le\mu\le x1}$, hence a Uniform
   $U(xn-\theta,x1)$. Your prior $\pi(\mu)=1$ is not Uniform but flat,
   as it is improper;
2. The Bayes estimator for the quadratic loss is indeed the posterior
   mean, which for a Uniform $U(xn-\theta,x1)$
   equals$$\frac{xn+x1-\theta}{2}$$
3. If $\theta$ is unknown, you first need to *set a prior on $\theta$*.
   For instance, I would take the scale improper prior $\pi(\theta)\propto 1/\theta$. You then need to *find the marginal posterior of $\mu$* given $x$ by integrating out $\theta$:$$\pi(\mu|\mathbf{x})=\int_0^\infty p(\theta,\mu|\mathbf{x})\,\text{d}\theta$$The joint posterior $p(\theta,\mu|\mathbf{x})$ can be derived from$$p(\theta,\mu|\mathbf{x})\propto\pi(\theta)\pi(\mu)f(\mathbf{x}|\mu,\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}\frac{1}{\theta^n}\mathbf{I}_{xn-\theta\le\mu\le x1}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now I can understand thoroughly about Bayesian estimator and Prior Function. So, for each unknown parameter, we will set a prior on it and find the joint posterior. Thank you very much ^^.